# Starting gitk on OS X displays a GreaseKit error

Tags: git, macos, gitk

When I load gitk (git version 1.6.5.1) on OS X (SL) I recieve an error/warning about GreaseKit:

`Error loading /Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/GreaseKit.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GreaseKit:  dlopen(/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/GreaseKit.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GreaseKit, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/GreaseKit.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GreaseKit: GC capability mismatch`

gitk does start and appears to be functional. Has anyone seen this? Any need to be concerned?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever version of [GreaseKit](http://8-p.info/greasekit/) is installed on your machine (as `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/GreaseKit.bundle`) is not GC-compatible with your `gitk` binary. It means that GreaseKit will not be available in `gitk`.

Unless you were planning on using GreaseKit inside `gitk` it is not a problem (does `gitk` even use WebKit?). Probably the only reason GreaseKit is loading is because its SIMBL configuration says to load GreaseKit into everything, regardless of whether it would ever be useful.

If no one on your machine is using GreaseKit, you might consider deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to edit the GreaseKit.bundle on your machine manually to only get included into Safari:

Navigate to /Users//Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/GreaseKit.bundle in Finder and choose to open the package.

Inside there is a Content folder which contains Info.plist. There you change the SIMBLTargetApplications Lines at the end from:

```
<key>SIMBLTargetApplications</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>BundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>*</string>
            <key>MaxBundleVersion</key>
            <string>*</string>
            <key>MinBundleVersion</key>
            <string>*</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

to

```
<key>SIMBLTargetApplications</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>BundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.Safari</string>
            <key>MaxBundleVersion</key>
            <string>*</string>
            <key>MinBundleVersion</key>
            <string>*</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

You may add other applications you want to have GreaseKit available for.

Alternatively just execute this in a Terminal Window to get to the file:

```
edit ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins/GreaseKit.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: I was having this same problem with MacVim and gitk. This fixed the issue for me perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on the same system. `gitk` would not even start for me, however.

Oddly enough, I found that if I executed `gitk` in a directory that was *not* actually under git control, it would start and complain about not being in a repository. Then the next time I executed `gitk` in an actual repository, it started without complaining about GreaseKit, and it's been all good since.

Or you could use GitX, which is quite similar and native OS X: http://gitx.frim.nl/